# How can I type rough breathing marks in Classical Greek using the Windows 11 Greek Polytonic keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, greek

I'm learning to use the Greek Polytonic keyboard in Windows 11 to type Classical Greek.

I can successfully type the following characters (using α as an example): ᾶ, ἀ, ἄ, ἂ, ά, ά, ἆ, ᾱ. For example, ἄ is produced by typing '/' + 'a' on my keyboard.

However, after spending about half an hour trying all of the key combinations I can think of and looking up shortcuts, I can't type rough breathing marks (i.e. Unicode U+0314 'Combining reversed comma above', see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_breathing)). Examples of characters that I think should be possible to type are these: ἵ, ἥ, ῥ. From a look online, it seems like '"' + 'a' (for example) should do this, but this just results in a normal alpha for me.

The results are exactly the same for me using the fonts Calibri, Palatino Linotype and Gentium Plus.

Unfortunately, the on-screen keyboard doesn't help: the indicated keys very clearly don't correspond to the actual keyboard combinations required on my keyboard for the characters that I can type.

I would be grateful if anyone is able to indicate where the problem might lie.

Comment: Is https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdhept.html at all helpful?

Comment: Also possibly of assistance: https://www.smith.edu/sites/default/files/media/Documents/Classics/Typing_In_Greek.pdf

Comment: Yes, it did! The keyboard that you linked to actually does reflect the right keyboard combinations and I was able to use it to figure out what the right keyboard combination was, thank you so much! I'll draft an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/enus/globalization/keyboards/kbdhept.html) shows the right keyboard layout, and helpfully shows how to type each diacritic using the deadkeys.

The rough breathings are typed using SHIFT + ' + letter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).